# Select all image elements with a specific src and no alt tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to match all image elements that have a specific `src` attribute and do not have an `alt` tag:

```
$('img[src="http://www.foo.com/bar.png"]not:([alt])')
```

But this isn't working.

I know I can find elements that DO have a specific alt tag:

```
$('img[src="http://www.foo.com/bar.png"][alt="Foo"]')
```

But how do I select ones that DON"T have an alt tag?

Answer (score 8):

You are writing wrong the `:not()` sentence:

```
 $('img[src="http://www.foo.com/bar.png"]:not([alt])')
```

### EDIT

Due comments requests, I add a stack snippet:

```js
$('img[src="http://www.foo.com/bar.png"]:not([alt])').css('border', '1px solid red');
```

```css
img {width: 100px; height:100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="http://www.foo.com/bar.png">
<img src="http://www.foo.com/bar.png" alt>
```

You only see the image with border that doesn't have `alt` attribute

Comment: Maybe add a JSFiddle?

Comment: Maybe it's better a stack snippet. Here you are :)

Comment: Good comment about stack snippets ... and now you might could take a coffee break so I can have some questions to answer ? .. :) ... want to get to 10k

Comment: I can't grow more reputation today, so all yours `:)`

Comment: My objective is the same, 10k rep :)

Comment: I see that it is ... hence my comment :)